# Rails Model Complex Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have a User Model and a through table between user's called Invite Model.

I want users to be able to invite others, be invited and have the association created.

My migration file looks like this:

```
class CreateInvites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invites do |t|
      t.integer :invited_id
      t.integer :inviter_id
      t.timestamps
    end
end
```

In my Invite Model I have the following:

```
class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :invited, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :inviter, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

I am unsure how to construct the user model with the appropriate associations. I want to a User to belong to one inviter and have many inviteds. How should I update my User Model appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => "Invite", :foreign_key => :inviter_id
  has_many :inviteds, :through => :sent_invites

  has_one :invite, :foreign_key => :invited_id
  has_one :inviter, :through => :invite
end
```

Sidebar, it is generally a good idea to add indexes to foreign keys like so:

```
class CreateInvites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invites do |t|
      t.references :invited
      t.references :inviter
      t.index :invited_id
      t.index :inviter_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: From [this website about indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join): "The join operation transforms data from a normalized model into a denormalized form that suits a specific processing purpose. Joining is particularly sensitive to disk seek latencies because it combines scattered data fragments. Proper indexing is again the best solution to reduce response times."  In this case, you'll be joining through the `invites` table frequently.